# How to remove tag from html using PHP?

Tags: php, html, explode

How to get `<div class="page">...</div>` from the HTML, then echo it out?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table class="a">...</table>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="page">...</div>
      <div class="footer">...</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to `explode` `<div class="page">` but result from `array[0]` only show code before that tag:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table class="a">...</table>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="page">...</div>
      <div class="footer">...</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I need is:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="page">...</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or better:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="page">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code I've tried so far is

```
$url = file_get_content("sample.html"); 
$cont1 = explode('<div class="wrap">', con1);
```

Is it possible to get before tag and after tag using explode?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you trying to parse existing HTML, or generate new HTML?

Comment: edit existing html... php is another script use to manipulate the html into new html with expected result as shown...

Comment: Ok, can you post the code you have so far for the above examples?

Comment: Do you want it before or after render to browser. Why you need to remove, instead created dynamic html ?

Comment: $url = file_get_content("sample.html");

$cont1 = explode('<div class="wrap">', con1);

Answer (score 2):

You would be much better off using DOMDocument and XPath to manipulate HTML(or XML) and although it can be difficult to get into - the benefits are huge.  DOMDocument can understand the structure and context of the document, so nesting and attributes become a core part of what you work with.

The above can be solved by

```
$html ='<html>
  <body>
    <table class="a">...</table>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="page">...</div>
      <div class="footer">...</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$div = $xp->query("//div[@class='page']");

echo $doc->saveHTML($div[0]);
```

The XPath expression here `//div[@class='page']` breaks down to any `<div>` tag which has a `class` attribute (denoted by using `@`) which is equal to `page`.

`query()` returns a list of matching nodes, so in the `saveHTML()` call, you need to use `[0]` to pick the first one.

This outputs...

```
<div class="page">...</div>
```

which you can use how you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to **Remove Certain Tags with Content**

Here is code example on how to remove only certain tags from a string with tag content

```
<?php
    $string = "<p>Awesome</p><b> Website</b><i> by Narayan</i>. Thanks for visiting";
    $tags = array("p", "i");

    echo preg_replace('#<(' . implode( '|', $tags) . ')(?:[^>]+)?>.*?</\1>#s', '', $string);
?>
```

Also, you can refer to below link(by Narayan),
http://qnimate.com/remove-html-tags-from-string-using-php/

Hope this will help you!